# Add an object created in Main class to an array in another class

Tags: java, arrays, class

Basically I have a main class which I declare my objects in and then in my Person class I have a method that is meant to add and object to an array created in Person class. For some reason this works for the first item but all the rest just return false (returns true if the item was added to array and false if the item was not added to the array). Here is my main method:

```
Department dept = new Department(4);
Person john = new Person("John", 35);
System.out.println(dept.addPerson(john));
```

and the class that is not working:

```
private Person[] people; 
private int count;
public Department(int count){
    people = new Person[count];
}
public boolean addPerson(Person x){
    boolean found = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
        if (people[i] == null){
            people[i] = x;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: Consider reading the help section on how to format the code in your posts. You're doing it wrong, making it hard to read, and in fact it's so off, it's hard for us to try to help correct it. Better for you to re-post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first call to the method, you're filling the entire array. So the indices will not be null the next call

```
public boolean addPerson(Person x){
    boolean found = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < people.length; i++){   // you're filling the array in this loop
        if (people[i] == null){
            people[i] = x;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to break your for loop after you add something. You fill up your array with the first person you add now.

```
for(int i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
    if (people[i] == null){
        people[i] = x;
        found = true;
    }
}
```

Should be

```
for(int i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
    if (people[i] == null){
        people[i] = x;
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that would probably be the better option. I just added the break as quickfix.

Comment: @EpicOkapi awesome that works! could you describe what is happening in the one i did? I'm trying to get my head around it, thanks!

Comment: @user3029711 Since you didn't break your for loop it just kept going until it gave a value to all the variables in your array.